Trying to redirect hotlinked pdf files using RewriteMap in http.conf and RewriteRules in .htaccess
I am trying to redirect external links to pdf files to the html page were the pdf is hosted.
I have updated /etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_main_global.conf, which is an include file for httpd.conf with:
#rewriteMap to stop hotlinking
RewriteMap pdf-mapping txt:/home/stakehol/public_html/pdf-mapping.txt

pdf-mapping.txt contains:
/stakeholder-register.pdf /stakeholder-register.html
/project-templates/lessons-learned-template.pdf /project-templates/lessons-learned-template.html
/project-templates/Exception%20Report.pdf /project-templates/prince-2-exception-report.html

It will have hundreds of URLs, but these three are just for testing.
In .htaccess I have added:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?stakeholdermap.com [NC]
RewriteCond ${pdf-mapping:$1} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.pdf)$ https://www.stakeholdermap.com/${pdf-mapping:$1} [R=302,L]

I have restarted Apache and the pdf files aren't redirecting. Ready to give up and just add links in the pdfs back to the page, but I want to charge for the pdfs at some point so...


RewriteRule ^(.*\.pdf)$ https://www.stakeholdermap.com/${pdf-mapping:$1} [R=302,L]


There are a couple of issues here with the URL-path you are capturing in the RewriteRule pattern:

The captured URL-path does not include a slash prefix, but you are including a slash prefix in the rewrite map. So this will never match.

The captured URL-path is %-decoded, so your 3rd URL in your rewrite map that includes an encoded space (ie. %20) will never match. However, a literal space is problematic in a TXT rewrite map (since spaces are delimiters and cannot be escaped). You need to capture the %-encoded URL instead.


A minor point (edge case) is that your second condition (RewriteCond directive) that checks the HTTP_REFERER allows external domains that simply uses your domain name as a subdomain to bypass your hotlinking. (The code below blocks this edge case by appending ($|/) to the pattern.)
Try the following instead, with your existing rewrite map:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com($|/) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(/[^?]+\.pdf)(\s|\?)
RewriteCond ${pdf-mapping:%1} (.+)
RewriteRule \.pdf$ https://www.example.com/%1 [R=302,L]

Explanation...
The RewriteRule pattern .pdf$ simply checks that the requested URL-path does end with .pdf.

The THE_REQUEST server variable contains the first line of the HTTP request request headers and will contain a string of the form (note that this includes the query string - if any):
GET /project-templates/Exception%20Report.pdf?query-string HTTP/1.1


The 3rd condition (that checks against THE_REQUEST) actually captures the requested URL-path. This is %-encoded as per the request. We are careful to exclude any query string from the captured URL as this would otherwise bypass your hotlink protection (the lookup would fail and the PDF file would be served).
The 4th condition captures the output of the rewrite map. Note that the %1 backreference is used in the TestString (as opposed to $1) that contains the first captured subpattern from the preceding condition. Note also the use of the + (1 or more) quantifier in the CondPattern so it is only successful when non-empty (you explicitly checked for non-empty, ie. !^$ - but a negated expression can not be used to capture).
The output from the rewrite map captured in the last condition is then used in the RewriteRule substitution string (%1), instead of calling the rewrite map again (although I expect this is probably cached internally anyway). Note the use of %1 again here, but this is a different value to %1 in the preceding condition's TestString.

Aside:

but I want to charge for the pdfs at some point

This hotlink protection does not provide much security as it is relatively trivial to bypass.

You allow an empty Referer header (first condition) so anyone typing the .pdf URL directly in the browser can access the file. Any external website can implement a referrer-policy (or simply set rel="noreferrer" on the anchor itself) that suppresses the Referer which will also bypass your hotlink protection.
(However, you generally need to allow an empty Referer since legitimate users themselves can suppress the Referer header in interests of "privacy". Blocking an empty Referer header could alienate some legitimate users.)

A malicious user can construct an HTTP request and send an entirely fake Referer header (matching your domain) and bypass your hotlink protection. Browser security prevents this behaviour but this is trivial using 3rd party scripts/tools such as CURL.


So, realistically, if the PDFs are to be restricted to paying customers then you would need to implement some kind of authentication/paywall and/or possibly generate one-off temporary/expiring links (the actual PDF files themselves being stored outside of the public domain).

Wow, thank you so much for this detailed and clear explanation. I have made the change, but it hasn't worked.

I am testing via this URL https://pm-training.net/stakeholder-register-template/ scroll down to Stakeholder Map: Free PDF template and click on the link 'Free PDF template'. That link goes direct to https://www.stakeholdermap.com/stakeholder-register.pdf and I want it to redirect to https://www.stakeholdermap.com/stakeholder-register.html.

@projectmonkey You have a rel="noreferrer" attribute on that link that suppresses the Referer - so this will bypass your hotlink protection as you have an exception for an empty Referer in your rule (see the last part of my answer). HOWEVER, I've just tried a dummy link myself and still it's not redirecting. I notice the response is coming from a LiteSpeed server, not Apache? Have you confirmed the rewrite map itself is working OK? Is .htaccess being processed? Any other directives/conflicts in .htaccess? Any errors in the server's error log?

@projectmonkey A "problem" with LiteSpeed is that it tends to silently suppress (fatal) errors, which makes debugging difficult. (Apache will naturally break on fatal errors.)

I have run the following checks:

I have run the following checks. 1. mod_rewrite is enabled. 2. checked syntax on Apache configuration. 3. checked the error logs for any relevant messages. 4. tested an existing rewrite rule. 5. checked filepath of map is correct. I am now going to look into LiteSpeed and check for conflicts in .htaccess. Thanks for your help!

Huh the server is using litespeed with apache. I think as part of a2hosting's speed proposition. I am now working with a2hosting support to find out if I need to change the config because of this. Also checking the permissions of pdf-mapping.txt as per https://forum.openlitespeed.org/threads/how-to-use-rewritemap.5715/

@projectmonkey LiteSpeed is sometimes used "instead of" Apache as it's essentially a drop-in replacement for Apache, although there are many (undocumented) breaking differences in my experience. Although sometimes LiteSpeed is still called "Apache" in some hosting control panels. (You wouldn't use "both" in my experience, unless perhaps LiteSpeed is used as a front-end proxy - but I've not seen that combination used before since Nginx is a much better option.) To clarify, you are managing your own server?

I wasn't, but to do this task I got root access. Thanks for the info. that makes a lot of sense.

so can't find vhost conf under lsws, but /usr/local/lsws/conf/httpd_config.xml has 'loadApacheConf set to 1 which I believe means lsws is using Apache config file.
